# How can I know if an attribute of an instance is an ImageField inside Django signals?

Tags: django, signals

This is my model (simplified):

```
class Book(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        ...
        img_1 = models.ImageField(null=True)
        img_2 = models.ImageField(null=True)
        img_3 = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

I have a post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def meli_publicar_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
       # get images
```

What I want here is to get all the fields that are images (img_1, img_2, etc.) and check if they are empty.

Comment: Would it make sense to store images in a separate model - `BookImage`, and link to that using `ForeignKey` field in `Book` model? That will depend upon why you're having 3 fields for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to link your images to your `Book` objects. It's will be more dynamic than actual.

Here is an example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BookImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="images")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Now, you don't have to check if images are empty before saving them since you can't add `BookImage` to a `Book` because `image` and `book` attributes don't have `null` parameter set to `True`.

Then, get url of the `Book` object  :

```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def meli_publicar_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for image in instance.images.all():
        print(image.image.url)
        # output : /media/images/filename.png
```

**Note: if you update the fields, `created` is set to `False` then it will not process code under `if kwargs.get('created', True):`.

If you want to keep your base models without `BookImage` object, then you can do that :

```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=Tel)
def meli_publicar_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   for attr, value in instance.__dict__.items():
       if isinstance(value, ImageFieldFile) and value:
           print(value.url)
           # output : /media/images/filename.png
```

Read [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) documentation for more information

Comment: Sorry. But I need to process the images inside the post_save signal in order to pass their path to an API. It would be useful to know how can I parse instance attributes that are ImageField. How can I do that?

Comment: This answer would be ok if I had two models, Book and BookImage, but it is not the case. I have the model Book and many images inside this model. What I want to do is to filter the instance elements that are ImageField type, inside the post_save signal. Like: if instance.attr is ImageField then etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the fields that are images and check if they are empty create method:

```
from django.db import models

def get_image_fields_values(obj):
    try:
        image_fields = [getattr(obj, f.name, None)
                        for f in obj._meta.get_fields()
                        if isinstance(f, models.ImageField)]
        # => [<ImageFieldFile: None>, <ImageFieldFile: movie/g-men.jpg>]
        image_values = [image.name for image in image_fields if image.name]
        # => ['movie/g-men.jpg']
    except AttributeError:
        return []
    return image_values
```

Then in post_save signal call that method like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def meli_publicar_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        images = get_image_fields_values(obj=instance)
```